# Retrieving selected row in dataGridView as an object

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I have a class like this:

```
public partial class AdressBokPerson
    {
        public long Session { get; set; }
        public string Förnamn { get; set; }
        public string Efternamn { get; set; }
        public string Mail { get; set; }
    }
```

Added to a list:

```
private readonly List<AdressBokPerson> _avp = new List<AdressBokPerson>();
```

With binding to a dataGridView like this:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = _avp;
```

So far so good.

**Here is my question:**

How do I find out 'which' object is selected when a row in the dataGridView is selected. I need to retrieve the **selected** object **AdressBokPerson** somehow.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You get the object by casting the *DataBoundItem* to the specified type:

```
AdressBokPerson currentObject = (AdressBokPerson)dataGridView1.CurrentRow.DataBoundItem;
```

Comment: That's the answer I'm always looking for when I work with DataGridViews. Thanks