# Get "data grid" data to text boxes using column name

Tags: c#, sql

I'm using this code to get my data to text boxes.

```
TextBoxName.Text = gridViewName.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

But, all the time this column index may not be the same one.

So, I need to get this datagrid value to the text box using its column name.

Is it possible?

If possible, what will be the code?

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET?

Comment: @John This is not a web application. Using C# and SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`gridView.SelectedRows[0].Cells` is a [DataGridViewCellCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) which has indexers for both integer and [string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ee9kshd(v=vs.110).aspx) parameters, so you should be able to get the selected row by column name:

```
TextBoxName.Text = gridViewName.SelectedRows[0].Cells["yourcolumnname"].Value.ToString();
```

Offtopic, but might be useful: try to use databinding as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19682526/retrieving-selected-row-in-datagridview-as-an-object).

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works... Sorry for the inconvenience